# Отсутвуют некоторые аннотации в Spring + Tomcat

Tags: spring, tomcat

Здравствуйте. Начал изучать Spring MVC, и в книге используют аннотации которые NetBeans не находит. Например [@Valid](/users/11718/validol) и @Inject. При "переводе" всего проекта на GlassFish всё находится.
Возможно ли такое на Томкате или придется использовать GlassFish? Как сделать чтобы такие аннотации "появились" при работе с Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это объясняется тем, что GlassFish это Application Server, а Tomcat это Servlet Container. Проще говоря, вместе с GlassFish также поставляются все необходимые библиотеки для поддержки JEE.

Чтобы всё заработало на Tomcat (и в других servlet containers) необходимо подключить эти библиотеки самостоятельно, например, с помощью Maven:

```
<!-- For @Inject -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
</dependency>

<!-- For @Valid -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```

Скорее всего, вам также понадобится и `hibernate-validator`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0.Alpha1</version>
</dependency>
```